# WatchKit button does not respond

Tags: ios, watchkit

The WatchKit buttons (`WKInterfaceButton`) in simulator do not respond to touch (click).  I'm using Xcode Beta 6.3.  I double-checked to ensure that the `enable` checkbox is checked in InterfaceBuider.

I even downloaded and ran the code from this WatchKit tutorial and even this one has the same problem (buttons do not respond and call their action methods):
http://cdn1.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/BitWatch-Final-1.2.zip

Comment: I am having identical problem with three different applications. iOS simulator either doesn't respond to clicks or responds to wrong ones?? It looks like a bug to me.

Comment: I have a similar problem, the touch is vertically translated 150 pixels from the original tap position and I can't tap buttons at the bottom at the screens. I'm also using Xcode Beta 6.3.

Comment: I also can not click on WKInterfaceButtons in the simulator running Xcode Beta 6.3

Comment: Please file a bug report: https://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Yep, there's indeed a bug in 6.3 where you cannot click buttons unless they're positioned at the top. WatchKit is very buggy right now.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use Xcode Beta 6.2 for touch actions to work.  This is a 6.3 bug.

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned, this is a bug right now.  I `positioned` my `button` to the `top` as a temporary workaround.  If positioned at the top the button does register clicks.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been fixed in Xcode 6.3 beta 2 that was released on Feb 23.